# Noise Attenuation with multiple files via Fourier Transformation

Tags: python, math, formula, librosa

I'm trying to implement the following formulas in a Jupyter notebook:

[image: Fourier Transform])

Below, I have the code for loading the Noisy (Y) and Noise files (D).

```
# Read audio data from file
noisy_speech = AudioSegment.from_wav('NoisySignal/Station/sp01_station_sn5.wav') 
y = noisy_speech.get_array_of_samples() # samples x(t)
y_f = noisy_speech.frame_rate # sampling rate f 
#window size: the number of samples per frame, each frame is of 30ms
win_length = int(y_f * 0.03)
#number of samples between two consecutive frames, by default, hop_length = win_length / 4
hop_length = int(win_length / 2)
Y = librosa.stft(np.float32(y), n_fft = 2048, window = 'hann', hop_length = hop_length, win_length = win_length)
mag_Y = abs(Y)
angle = np.angle(Y)
print(Y.shape)
```

```
# Read audio data from file
n_speech = AudioSegment.from_wav('Noise/Station/Station_1.wav') 
d = n_speech.get_array_of_samples() # samples x(t)
d_f = n_speech.frame_rate # sampling rate f 
#window size: the number of samples per frame, each frame is of 30ms
win_length = int(d_f * 0.03)
#number of samples between two consecutive frames, by default, hop_length = win_length / 4
hop_length = int(win_length / 2)
D = librosa.stft(np.float32(y), n_fft = 2048, window = 'hann', hop_length = hop_length, win_length = win_length)
mag_D = abs(D)
means_mag_D = np.mean(mag_D, axis = 1)
```

So the array in Y & D, each column is a frame.

How would I implement the above formula for S-hat?

Is there a library that can do it for me, if not, how would I write it from scratch?

Also, if anyone has a link to a video or document for writing formulas to code, that would be helpful as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The formula doesn't involve any calculus or anything like that so you can simply use numpy. Work out how to do each of the individual mathematical operations using numpy and then put them all together.

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.random(20)
d = np.random.random(20)

right = 1 - (d**2)/(y**2)  # Calculate the right side of the max equation
right[right < 0] = 0  # Equivalent to max(0, right)
h = right**0.5
s_hat = h*y
```